# JPL program into Html

Tags: java, html, prolog, java-web-start

I 've made a Java-Prolog program for school purposes and i want to run it to web.. I read about Html in Prolog but i've already made a gui in java and i don't want to make another..I want to run this gui i made into web.. Is there any way?
I've also tried JWS but there are problems loading prolog files..So i am stuck on it..Any help? 
With this code in netbeans i  load prolog file..but in JNLP it doesn't load it..

```
Term consult_arg[] = {
            new Atom(Diagnosis.class.getResource("new.pl").getPath())
        };
        Query consult_query
                = new Query(
                        "consult",
                        consult_arg);

        boolean consulted = consult_query.hasSolution();

        if (!consulted) {
            System.err.println("Consult failed");
            System.exit(1);

        }
```

Comment: Would it be simpler to use a Java implementation of Prolog such as JIProlog?

Comment: What exactly is that?

Comment: I use this way for school purposes so i couldn't do something else...no i want to know if there is anyway to run it to web exactly as it is...

Comment: *".. i want to run it to web."* As a Java app.? Applet.  But the 'window of opportunity' to use embedded applets is quickly disappearing.  The next best thing to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  (User can launch the GUI from a link on a web page.)

Comment: In Java Web Start i have problem loading the prolog file..
It shows an exception finding source link... In netbeans runs well but when i run it from cmd or from a web page it throws this exception.. 


`Prolog Exception : existence_error source link`

Comment: Where is placed your Prolog file? Using Java Web Start your application works in sandbox. Your Prolog file need to visible / downloadable by using http or you can provide a whole path to your file. - The second solution will work only on your machine.

Comment: Prolog file is inside the jar...